# Facebook doesn't work in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, firefox, chromium, facebook

since two days I can't connect to facebook any more. All other pages work. I tried it from Firefox as well as from Chromium (both on ubuntu 12.10). The strange thing is, that it is working on Windows.

I also already changed the MTU to `1492`.

I run curl, too:

```
* About to connect() to facebook.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 66.220.152.19...
* connected
* Connected to facebook.com (66.220.152.19) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: facebook.com
> Accept: */*
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Location: https://facebook.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< X-FB-Debug: nvdzA4R/GF2tDj/80QDgq5VV2OM8KYeRDz2Zm9mwdxM=
< Date: Tue, 29 Jan 2013 16:24:50 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host facebook.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Has anybody an idea, what it could be?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "can't connect' mean? What happens in the two browsers when you try to load facebook.com? Is only facebook.com affected? What happens if you try facebook.org?
Can you bring up a terminal and try `ping -c1 facebook.com`? What ip-adress, if any, is in the result? Why have you been changing the MTU? There's very rarely any reason to meddle with such details of the network stack for non-professionals.

Comment: Facebook.com, facebook.org and facebook.de are bringing a timeout. The result of the ping is the IP 69.171.237.24, (which should be right, or?). I changed the MTU because I found a similar problem here: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34635/my-facebook-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-10-10-but-works-on-windows-xp)

Comment: Hmm, what if you `curl -v facebook.com` in the terminal? Might be a lot of text, please update the question, instead of posting as comment.

Comment: Same problem on 12.04.

Comment: the curl output says the connection worked, status 302 means you got redirected to the https version.   This is a problem with chromium/firefox, not your network.

Comment: This shows the connection is working; as @ImaginaryRobots said you've just been redirected to HTTPS. Now run `curl -v https://facebook.com` and paste the output

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots Sounds like you can post an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This would remove all the custom settings, bookmarks, history, cookies, saved passwords and co.**

- Open a terminal and run `rm -rf ~/.mozilla`
- Open Firefox and go to Facebook again.

This might help: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7296/discussion-between-alen-and-michael-tanner, which is a chat link from the question: https://askubuntu.com/q/248963/83046.

Comment: Won't this remove custom settings, bookmarks, history, cookies, saved password & co.? Isn't there a less destructive solution?

Comment: Ofcourse, it would.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to specify it explicitly then? ;-)

Comment: There! In your words :)

Comment: Hey, thank you, that helped! Do you know why that problem occours? I had also in mind, that it coult be connected with the https. But other https sites worked, too.

Comment: Well it may be because the permissions of your `cache` folder were messed up. So, probably facebook couldn't save anything in that directory. It's just a guess though.

Comment: Unfortunately it worked for one day, but today I have the same problem again... Any suggestions?

Comment: That's weird. Open a terminal and see the permissions of `~/.mozilla` directory using `ls -ld ~/.mozilla`

Comment: `drwx------ 4 lukas lukas 4096 Jan 29 17:53 /home/lukas/.mozilla` After a reeboot today everything was fine again. Perhaps it's working now.... let's see.

Comment: Right. Clearly no one other than the user or the creator himself can write into the folder. Run the following command: `chmod -R 776 ~/.mozilla`